# Scanner nextLine() occasionally skips input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here is my code

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Last name: ");
lastName = keyboard.nextLine(); 

System.out.print("First name: ");
firstName = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.print("Email address: ");
emailAddress = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.print("Username: ");
username = keyboard.nextLine();
```

and  it outputs this

```
Last name: First name:
```

Basically it skips letting me enter `lastName` and goes straight to the prompt for `firstName`.

However, if I use `keyboard.next()` instead of `keyboard.nextLine()`, it works fine. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me guess -- you've got code not shown that uses the Scanner above the attempt to get lastName. In that attempt, you're not handling the end of line token, and so it's left dangling, only to be swallowed by the call to `nextLine()` where you attempt to get `lastName`.

For example, if you have this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int number = keyboard.nextInt();  // dangling EOL token here
System.out.print("Last name: ");
lastName = keyboard.nextLine();
```

You're going to have problems.

One solution, whenever you leave the EOL token dangling, swallow it by calling `keyboard.nextLine()`.

e.g.,

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int number = keyboard.nextInt();  
keyboard.nextLine();  // **** add this to swallow EOL token
System.out.print("Last name: ");
lastName = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: That's exactly what was happening. Thanks!

Comment: @jsan: You're welcome. Most of us have stumbled across this issue when starting out using Scanner. Another possible solution is to use one Scanner to get lines, and then another to handle the text in the line, which is fine, as long as you close any Scanners after use (except the one linked to the System.in.